# Waiting until a specific time to start threads

Tags: python, multithreading, timer

Im writing a script in which im looking to get the current time, and wait until that certain time, or until the hour hits :00.
I am working with python requests, and would like to make sort of a "timer" that would sleep until the hour or :00

Once the time hits :00, i want it to run the threads.
I don't have any code started on this, so I am coming to ask.

Any tips on how to do this?

Comment: I suggest you look at the Python `sched` module.  https://docs.python.org/3/library/sched.html

Comment: @TimRoberts Looking at the example I am not sure if this is what I'm looking for specifically for my script. I am not familiar with this library, so do you have any other examples or experience working with it? The example shown may not be suitable for my job.

Comment: Perhaps https://schedule.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ would do more of the work for you.